# Как сделать добавление ключей и значений в словарь, чтобы они сохранялись и пополнялись в течении пользования программой?

Tags: python, dict

у меня уже что-то получилось, но когда я выхожу из цикла и захожу обратно, оказывается что все внесенные ключи и значения не сохранились, как это исправить ?

```
word = {
    'hi': 'hello',
    'hello': 'world',
}

while True:
    key = input(str('введите ключ: '))
    volume = input(str('введите значение: '))
    word.update({key: volume})
    print(word)
    if key == 'стоп':
        break
```

Comment: А как вы заходите в цикл и выходите из него? Просто сделайте так, чтобы инициализация словаря была вне этого ещё одного цикла, про который вы говорите.

Comment: блок if key == 'стоп':   я бы перенес выше под строку key = input(str('введите ключ: ')). Зачем слово 'стоп' добавлять в словарь.

Comment: вход не проблема, просто добавлю в if, а выход там уже есть тоже через if, но как их сохранить ? 
я пока думаю о том чтобы записывать внесенные данные в текстовый документ .txt, а потом при необходимости использовать оттуда, но может у кого-то есть идея более здравая ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начну с того, что тут допущена ошибка `input(str('введите ключ: '))`, вы переводите строку в строку, что не имеет смысла.
А чтобы программа работала, достаточно условие поставить после запроса ключа.

```
word = {
    'hi': 'hello',
    'hello': 'world',
}

while True:
    key = input('введите ключ: ')
    if key == 'стоп':
        break
    volume = input('введите значение: ')
    word.update({key: volume})
    print(word)
```

При выходе из цикла если обратиться к переменной word, оттуда ничего не пропадает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]